# Unlocking Nexus One without pressing the power button

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens, nexus-one

The power button on my Nexus One doesnt work smoothly any more, sometimes taking nearly half a dozen attempts before the unlock screen appears on the phone. I was wondering is there is any other way to invoke the unlock screen on my phone, apart from pressing the power button. I have Gingerbread 2.3.4 on my phone.

Comment: There are custom roms like CyanogenMod that allows you to unlock using your trackball, dont know if there on market is and app for that,... some minutes ago... hey here is one https://market.android.com/details?id=org.liberty.android.anyunlock&feature=search_result , there are other apps like this

Comment: also, you should consider to change you nexus one case/body, i mean a new housing http://shop.brando.com/google-nexus-one-replacement-housing_p4572c587d4.html

Comment: @yeradis, I can confirm that AnyUnlock and other similar apps do work on the Nexus One.  Go ahead and post that as an answer.

Comment: @Yeradis thanks a million! Problem solved, AnyUnlock works wonderfully on my Nexus One. Incidentally, also discovered Intelligent Keylock Unlocker which uses the proximity sensor to enable or disable the screen when things are close to it. Not the same thing I was looking for but again, quite nifty.   https://market.android.com/details?id=com.splunchy.android.keyguard

Comment: yes, really nice, the problem is that that using the proximity sensor will drain your battery because will be running always, is not like calls that just use it when you get it

Comment: @yeradis Nice about the new case, now I wish I had a Nexus :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my comment as an answer xD

There are custom roms like CyanogenMod that allows you to unlock using your trackball, dont know if there on market is and app for that...

--some minutes ago...--

hey there is one at https://market.android.com/details?id=org.liberty.android.anyunlock&feature=search_result called AnyUnlock,

there are other apps like this.... --as you discovered xD --

pd: rate with 100 for the effort :p